# Free throws in basketball game - Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution

The random variable $X_i$ indicates whether in a basketball game the $i$-th free throw is hit ($X_i = 1$) or not ($X_i = 0$).
$10$ free throws are executed, so that $i = 1,\ldots 10$.
It holds that $P(X_i=0)=0,3$ and $P(X_i=1)=0,7$. 
X denotes the sum of these ten independent random variables: $X = \sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i$.

(a) Determine $P (X = 8)$. What does this probability mean in terms of content?

(b) What is the probability that the number of hits is at most five?

(c) Which number of hits can we expect on average?

$$$$

(a) Does it hold that $P(X=8)=0,3^2\cdot 0,7^8=0.0051883209$ ? That would mean that the probability that 8 of 10 free throws were successful is equal to $0,5\%$.

Is this correct?

(b) We want to calculate the probability $P(X\geq 5)$, which is equal to $P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)=0,3^9\cdot 0,7^1+0,3^8\cdot 0,7^2+0,3^7\cdot 0,7^3+0,3^6\cdot 0,7^4+0,3^5\cdot 0,7^5=0.0007043841$, or not?

(c) We are asked to calculate the expected value, aren't we? Is this equal to $$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i\cdot P(X=x_i)\\ =1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)+3\cdot P(X=3)+\ldots 9\cdot P(X=9)+10\cdot P(X=10)$$ or not?

Comment: Not strictly part of the problem asked, but the assumption throws are independent is unrealistic as players of a certain ability tend to play together, certain players get more free throws, and substitutions will make free throws where $i$ are closer together, positively correlated.

Comment: Use the binomial probability distribution. You can easily find formulae for its mean and expected value.

Comment: It would help the formatting if you used a point as the decimal separator; using a comma adds an extra space by default because it's normally used in lists.

Comment: @JiK Don't be USA-centric :-) .  Much of the world uses a comma as the decimal delineator, so if anything this is StackExchange's fault for not having universal formatting capability.

Comment: @ProducerofBS On the other hand :-), in the absence of any information on who is playing against whom, who the referees are, and which players had a fight with their wives and are really grumpy,  the best we can do is assign uniform probabilities.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it does say it's a game of basketball though.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't care about fault, I care about readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a) Your calculation of P(X = 8) is erroneous. You failed to consider the fact that $0,3^2⋅0,7^8$ only considers 1 case of 8 hits and 2 misses. e.g. HHHHHHHHMM. In fact, there are $\frac{10!}{2!8!}$ cases (using combinatorics), leading to $\frac{10!}{2!8!}*(0,3^2⋅0,7^8)$ being the correct solution for P(X=8). Your definition of the probability is also a bit vague. I would phrase it in this way "the probability that 8 of 10 free throws were successfully hit"

(b) You have misinterpreted the question. The number of hits is at most 5, so X should be at most 5. Hence, we should find the $P(X\le 5)$. You would have to use a Binomial Distribution for this. There are 10 independent free throws, with a P(successful hit) = $P(X_i=1)$ = 0.7. Hence, X~B(10,0.7). You can use a calculator or Excel to find $P(X\le 5)$ from there. (BinomCDF)

(c) E(X) = np for a Binomial Distribution. In this case, E(X) = 10 * 0.7 = 7. For a more comprehensive answer, we can use the general formula E(X) = $\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_ip_i$. Find all the $P(X=x_i)$ and mutiply it with all the corresponding $x_i$ values. Sum the product up to find E(X).

Hope this helps.

Comment: At the last part, isn't it $E(X)=10\cdot 0.7=7$ instead of $3$ ?

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry about that. Replace the P(successful hit) in part (b) by 0.7, so the binomial is actually X~B(10,0.7). For (c), E(X) = 10*0.7 = 7. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I got it now! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: Regarding (b), while she wrote >=, she actually enumerated cases with x<5, although she orgot theh x = 0 case, and didn't include the binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 6):

The key for the whole question is to identify the distribution of $X$ which is a sum of i.i.d of Bernoulli distribution.

Hence $X \sim Bin(10, 0.7)$.

With this tool, you should be able to solve every part.

In particular

$$Pr(X=x) = \binom{10}x 0.7^x\cdot 0.3^{10-x}$$

also, we know the closed form formula for its expectation.

Comment: Is it not a binomial distribution?

Comment: Do we have that the distribution of $X$ is a sum of i.i.d of Bernoulli distribution because each of the $X_i$'s can just take the values $0$ or $1$ ?

Comment: yes, $X_i$ take binary value are they are iid acccording to the assumption of the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must be able to determine that $X\sim Binomial (n=10,p=0.7)$, where $p$ is the probability of a made free throw. From there, you can proceed by noting that $P[X=x]= {n\choose k}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k={10\choose k}(0.3)^{10-k}(0.7)^k$. You can also interpret $P[X=x]$ as the probability that the number of made free throws out of 10 is $x$.
Then

(a) Calculate $P[X=8]$. Do the interpretation. :)

(b) Calculate $P[X\le 5]=P[X=0]+P[X=1]+P[X=2]+P[X=3]+P[X=4]+P[X=5]$.

(c) The mean of a $X\sim Binomial(n,p)$ is $np$.

Comment: I mean $P[X=k]$, not $P[X=x]$.

Comment: Include this comment of yours in the answer section by editing.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, $0.3^2.0.7^8$ represents the probability that 8 out of 10 free throws are made, but you can arrange $8$ made FT and $2$ missed FT in different ways, specifically $^{10}C_2$ ways, so the actual probability is $^{10}C_2.0.3^2.0.7^8$.

In other words, $0.3^2.0.7^8$ represents the probability of hitting $8$ out of $10$ FT in just **one** of the many possible ways (e.g. hitting the first $8$ FT and missing the last $2$).

Similarly you can solve the second part, but note that you have to calculate $P(X \leq 5)$ (at most $5$ FT).

For the third part, use linearity of expectation - $E[X] = \sum_iE[X_i]$. Alternatively, as already noted by you and Producer of BS, the experiment can be described by a binomial probability distribution, whose expectation is $E[X = n] = np$, where $p$ is the probability of a made FT.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning this is binomial probability

Comment: Thank you!! :-)